# Keyboard display is fixed

Tags: react-native

I want the keyboard to always be displayed on the screen

To get this I use this notation for View

`keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'`

The problem is that in Debug it works but when I generate APK it doesn't work anymore. As if it wasn't included

RN: 0.61.2